# Magento 2.4.6 : Saving a new configurable product is slow

Tags: performance, product, magento2.4

I have magento 2.4.6 open source running on Ubuntu server (php 8.1.2 / mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.16-MariaDB).

When creating a new configurable product, saving it takes several minutes.

NB: Editing and saving an existing product is working well

I tryed the mariadb settings :

```
optimizer_switch = "rowid_filter=off"
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
```

I also configured php.ini files as suggested by several posts.
Pb is still there.

Thank you for your help,